Nginx rewrite directive loops, location with trailing slash doesn't match, why?
My goal is to serve requests from mobile devices on a different URL (a specific location) than the generic one, used for desktop version of my website.
I also need to serve files from a different document root, which should be seen as the base path (I don't want my location to be part of the directory structure).
I have this config (extract):
    location / {
        if ($http_user_agent ~* '(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|webOS|Windows Phone)') {
            rewrite ^ /mobile/ permanent;
        }
        index  index.html index.htm;
    } 

    location /mobile/ {
        root /my/mobile/website;            # new document root
        rewrite ^/mobile(.*)$ $1 break;     # strip /mobile prefix from the path
#        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;  # I tried this (don't know exactly what this should do), but it doesn't work anyway
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

This doesn't work and is causing a redirection loop.
It seems that requests to www.mydomain.com/mobile/ aren't matched from the location /mobile/ section but still fall into location /, causing a 301 redirect loop.
If I leave the rewrite ^/mobile(.*)$ $1 break; directive away it works, I get an index.html page that I placed into /my/mobile/website/mobile directory for testing, but that's not where my files should be served from.
What am I missing?

I am guessing that the problem is index.

The original URL is /mobile/.
The rewrite...break changes the URL to / but remains inside the same location block to continue processing the request.
The index directive changes the URL to /index.html then searches for a matching location which moves to the other location block, resulting in a redirection loop.


You could consider using alias to replace both root and rewrite...break.
For example:
location /mobile/ {
    alias /my/mobile/website/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

Note that the location and alias statements should both end with / or neither end with / for correct alias operation.

I didn't know that the index directive would trigger a new search like a redirect, this indeed explains what's happening. I had already tried with alias, but didn't included the trailing slash... now it works! Thanks.

@Bozzy https://nginx.org/r/index … It should be noted that using an index file causes an internal redirect :-)
